# Compare date and time to todays date and time

Tags: mysql, sql, drupal-7

What would be the best way in MySQL to compare date and time on this format 
`dd.mm.yyyy min.sec (05.03.2019 10.30)` 
to the date and time right now?

The data is stored as type datetime in the database

Would i need to reformat my data, if so, how?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Could you describe data type for your date - it's a string or date/timestamp?

Comment: MySQL
But i, doing the query over drupal 7 with db_select

Comment: Step 1: Use proper date/time data types.

Comment: The data is stored as type datetime

Comment: Do you want the difference in terms of months, days or minutes/seconds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To only return true if the date has not passed

This would do the trick directly as a query in my db:

```
SELECT c.entity_id AS entity_id, 
c.field_course_category_terms_tid AS field_terms_tid,
e.entity_type AS entity_type, 
e.field_end_date_value AS field_end_date_value
FROM 
field_data_field_terms c
INNER JOIN field_data_field_end_date e ON c.entity_id = e.entity_id
WHERE
e.field_end_date_value > curdate()
```

In my drupal query this did the trick:

```
$query = db_select('table1', 'c');
$query->innerJoin('table2', 'e', 'c.entity_id = e.entity_id');
$query->fields('c',array('entity_id','field_terms_tid'))
  ->fields('e',array('entity_type', 'field_end_date_value'))
  ->where('e.field_end_date_value  now()');
  ->execute();
$result = $result->fetchAll();
```